# SFSafariViewController Done button not working / touch area too small

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, sfsafariviewcontroller

I am presenting a link in SFSafariViewController as follows:

```
SFSafariViewController *sfvc = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:myurl];
sfvc.preferredControlTintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
sfvc.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:sfvc animated:YES];
```

I have added delegate `SFSafariViewControllerDelegate` and method:

```
- (void)safariViewControllerDidFinish:(SFSafariViewController *)controller{
    NSLog(@"safariViewControllerDidFinish");
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

However, when I tap the "Done" button, it often doesn't work. Especially with left hand, it doesn't ever work. However when I tap with right hand with a specific angle, it does work. This seems to indicate that the touch area for "Done" button is too small.

If I use swipe from left edge, then that works.

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out. I used XCode's "Debug View Hierarchy" and noticed that the left side of the entire `SFSafariViewController` was being overlayed by the UINavigationController's left edge swipe detection view and a second left edge swipe detection view. Maybe the SFSafariViewController comes with it's own left edge swipe detection view. The second view was overlapping the "Done" button touch area.

[image]

Then I read somewhere that SFSafariViewController should only be presented using `presentViewController`.

So I removed the delegate method and used this instead:

```
SFSafariViewController *sfvc = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:myurl];
sfvc.preferredControlTintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
[self presentViewController:sfvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This works perfectly.
Surprisingly, presenting this way, the swipe from left edge still seems to work fine. Looking through XCode's "Debug View Hierarchy", I notice only a single left edge swipe detection view:

[image]